# How to enable audio on a server installation?

Tags: 14.04, server, sound, thinkpad

I've installed an ubuntu version without GUI, namely ubuntu 14.04 Server edition, and therefor the audio is not enabled.
I would like to play audio on this server installation.
I've read many workarounds from other people who had the same problem, no one workaround worked for me.
I have a Thinkpad X120e.

Edit:

With this post I prefer to have a solution to use without a GUI.

Comment: What was your reason for installing server edition on a laptop? Do you want to play sound from the command line and if so, what sounds? Or are you asking how to install a desktop environment?

Comment: @neon_overload The main reason is don't like GUI's, and prefer to use only a window manager when needed, which is i3.

Comment: The second part of my question was what sounds are you wanting to play?  Like, music files?

Answer (score 0):

You can install a desktop environment with:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

This effectively adds a desktop environment to your installation, which is what you would have had if you hadn't used the server edition installer.

Comment: Wouldn't he be better off just installing pulseaudio instead of a full desktop environment?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, this is not the solution I prefer. I've installed my preferred GUI, named i3, which I use when I need a GUI. This GUI doesn't configure audio automatically. I want to be able to play audio, as well in non-GUI as  in GUI environment.